# Validating Based on Status PickList

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have a Field called Form_Type__c which different form numbers
like 460,461,465...

If the Form_Type__c has either values of 461/465 and if the Status__c = "Approved" Then There should be an Error saying Fill the ACSD Field Value is Required

but my code accepts all the values and saying ASCD Required

Here is the Validation Formula

> OR(Form_Type__c = "461" || Form_Type__c = "465",AND(ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Approved")))

Answer (score 3):

Your current formula is returning true (throwing the error) if **one or more** of the following is true: `Form_Type__c = 461`, `Form_Type__c = 465`, `Status__c = Approved`.

The OR operator returns true if either of its two conditions are met. In your case, since you have a nested OR, if either `Form_Type__c = "461"` or `Form_Type__c = "465"` is true, then the first outer OR condition is met, returning true; additionally, if the second condition of the nested OR `ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Approved")` is true, your OR operator also returns true. As a side note...currently, your AND operator is doing nothing, as you have only one condition inside of it.

Either of these will work, depending on your preferred syntax:

```
(Form_Type__c = "461" || Form_Type__c = "465") && ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Approved")
```

or alternatively,

```
AND( OR(Form_Type__c = "461", Form_Type__c = "465"), ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Approved"))
```